# How to return string and numeric values under 1 column

Tags: xml, splunk

I am trying to extract the schema version of customers from a specific application. As per design customers can use any schema number they want. Some of the customers are inserting for example the value 6.0 and others '6.0', when I want to return the number of the results per schema, splunk returns those values as separate columns.
When I use convert or eval (tostring, tonumber) some of the values are not returned.

how can I achieve that none of the data are going to be lost but I will get 1 column for 6.0 and '6.0'?

stats count by customerAccount, schemaVersion | xyseries customerAccount schemaVersion count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting multiple columns because `xyseries` is converting the multiple values in the 'schemaVersion' column into multiple columns.  Normalize the schema versions and you will have fewer columns and may no longer need `xyseries`.

Regrettably, there is no one method to normalize data - it depends on the nature of the data itself.  As you've discovered, `tonumber` fails when the input string is not a valid number.  You can remove quotation marks with `| eval schemaVersion=trim(schemaVersion, "'\"")`.  The second argument can be expanded to any character you want removed from the ends of the version strings.

Comment: Thank you. I will give it a go in the morning.